# Remove Multiple Snapshots at once in PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I am trying to delete old snapshots after patching using PowerCLI.  The code i am using now is:

```
Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | Remove-Snapshot -confirm$false
```

It works great...but it only removes one at a time, and i would like it to do 2-3 at a time.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to look at getting your VM's, then removing them as individual jobs. Check out PoshRSJob on GitHub - https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob

Answer (score 0):

This code will remove multiple snapshots from all virtual machines:

```
Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | % { Remove-Snapshot $_ -Confirm:$false }
```

I would recommend selecting a single virtual machine and testing first:

```
$VM = Get-VM -Name 'My Virtual Machine'
$VM | Get-Snapshot | % { Remove-Snapshot $_ -Confirm:$false }
```

Tested to work on PowerCLI 6.5.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the 'RunAsync' parameter. This will create the task and then move onto the next task without waiting for the prior task to complete.

Example:

```
Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | Remove-Snapshot -RunAsync -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Wouldn't "-runasync" remove all the snapshots at once?  I will have snapshots on about 50 servers during a patch cycle and only want to remove 3 at a time...

Comment: It would remove all of them at the same time. You probably want to look into something like PowerShell threading if you want to be that granular.